# MissingMethodException: Method 'Player1Movement.OnJump' not found. Unity Input Manager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press W or S this section of the code throws a missing exception error despite it being ran due to the Debug log acutally outputting... I really have no idea why this is happening or if its related to [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/missingmethodexception-method-not-found.1337873/)

```cs
  private void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {

       rbody.velocity = Vector2.up * jPower;
        // this is the "jump" action callback method
        Debug.Log(context);
    }
```

Full Error:

```cs
MissingMethodException: Method 'Player1Movement.OnJump' not found.
System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object target, System.Object[] providedArgs, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.String[] namedParams) (at <b89873cb176e44a995a4781c7487d410>:0)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMember (System.Object behaviour, System.String name, System.Object variable) (at <e97d84204f8d4aef92b538c5bab948f1>:0)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0(NativeInputUpdateType, NativeInputEventBuffer*)
UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate(NativeInputUpdateType, IntPtr)
```

What the debug statement was able to gather:

```cs
{ action=Player/Jump[/Keyboard/upArrow] phase=Performed time=85.8843302000001 control=Key:/Keyboard/upArrow value=1 interaction= }
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Player1Movement:OnJump (UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction/CallbackContext) (at Assets/Player1Movement.cs:37)
Player1Movement:<Awake>b__6_0 (UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction/CallbackContext) (at Assets/Player1Movement.cs:22)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.NativeInputRuntime/<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0 (UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputUpdateType,UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputEventBuffer*)
UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate (UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputUpdateType,intptr)
```

The code in question (and the only C# script in the Unity project), Do note the player movement works just fine, its jumping that is throwing errors:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Player1Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // assign the actions asset to this field in the inspector:
    public InputActionAsset actions;
    public float speed;
    public float jPower;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rbody;
   public float JumpCooldown; 
    // private field to store move action reference
    private InputAction moveAction;

    void Awake()
    {
        // find the "move" action, and keep the reference to it, for use in Update
        moveAction = actions.FindActionMap("Player").FindAction("Move");

        // for the "jump" action, we add a callback method for when it is performed
        Debug.Log("Subscribing to Jump action performed event.");
        actions.FindActionMap("Player").FindAction("Jump").performed += (context) => OnJump(context);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // our update loop polls the "move" action value each frame
        Vector2 moveVector = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            rbody.velocity = moveVector * speed;
    }

    private void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {

       rbody.velocity = Vector2.up * jPower;
        // this is the "jump" action callback method
        Debug.Log(context);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        actions.FindActionMap("Player").Enable();
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        actions.FindActionMap("Player").Disable();
    }
}
```

I tried checking the code with GPT, refering documentation, asking in the Unity discord, I narrowed down the issue to something related to `InputAction.CallbackContext context` But why or what it is I am unsure of. I am a little rusty with Unity so I applogie if this is an bad question. I searched around on stack overflow and only found the issue happening in .Net projects (outside of the Unity Fourms post linked above)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by changing this to invoke unity events

[image: it was previously on 'send messages'] has been changed to
[image: it has been set to 'invoke unity events']